# Specifying CSS for desktop clients only in HTML emails

Tags: css, html-email

I'm trying to include CSS that would affect only desktop email clients and not mobile ones.

In the example below, I've included CSS for all clients and then tried to override that with CSS declarations intended only for mobile clients with a max-width 480px media query.

I've also tried using `@media screen and (min-width: 800px)` but that seems be ignored by all of the email clients we're testing.

However, when I test the emails in Litmus all of the e-mail clients, even desktop based ones, are displaying the table at 100% width as opposed 500px

```
table[id="socialTbl"] {
    width: 500px !important;
    max-width: 500px !important;
}

table[id="locations"] {
    width: 500px !important;
    max-width: 500px !important;
}



/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */

table[id="socialTbl"] {
    width: 100% !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
}

table[id="locations"] {
    width: 100% !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your desktop clients, all CSS needs to be inline, media-queries will only work for your mobile devices.

This is a really great overview on the process from Campaign Monitor - http://www.campaignmonitor.com/guides/mobile/

Comment: Exactly, with HTML email, you design desktop-first (these are the dumb clients) and add (limited) CSS for mobile. The coverage is all over the place, services like litmus offer device testing, but I always test on colleague's devices, too. Pay special attention to BlackBerries: dumb clients with high proliferation in the corporate world.